# How to construct DTO in Java if I want to hold JSON object of below type. Using Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, azure-cosmosdb

```
{
   "Name":"Satyajit",
   "LastName":"Mohanty",
   "A":{
      "B":"None",
      "C":[
         {
            "D":"Hello",
            "E":"Hi",
            "F":{
               "key":"Phone",
               "value":"Ph1"
            },
            "G":{
               "key":"Phone",
               "value":"Ph1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Like the JSON is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    MainObjectDto {
     private String Name;
     private String LastName;
     private ADto A;
     }
     
     ADto {
      private String B;
      private CDto[] C;
     }
     
     CDto {
      private String D;
      private String E;
      private FDto F;
      private GDto G;
     }
     
     FDto {
      private String key;
      private String value;
     }
     
     GDto {
      private String key;
      private String value;
     }
```